# How to generate Bitcoin private - public keys with ECDSA module?

Tags: address, ecdsa, python

Pretty same question was asked [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13970/python-code-to-generate-private-ecdsa-key), but maybe there is a way to generate keys using [ecdsa](https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa) module in just a few lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
import ecdsa
print(ecdsa.SigningKey.generate(curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).to_string())
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! So, when I'm runnnig your code, I'm getting something like `b'\xe9+\xf7\x97A\.....`. How can I convert it to a usual string? `str()` and `.decode('utf-8')` don't work :(

Comment: It's a `bytes` type. Interpreting it as ascii or as UTF-8 doesn't make any sense. Are you trying to convert to hex, or are you trying to print raw bytes to the terminal?

Comment: Well, I mean that usually ECDSA private key looks like `18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725` according to [this](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses). So, how can I get an address which looks the same?

Comment: *a key which looks the same

Comment: Use `binascii.hexlify(key.to_string()).decode('ascii').upper()`